# mysql Left join returns wrong value on group by

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have problem with Left join with group by.I am getting net rate 336.83 whereas actual is only 25.91

```
SELECT L.EnquiryId,L.Levelcode, im.imcode, im.ItemName, im.ItemDescription, cs.conditionofsupply, rm.rawmaterial, L.Validity, ROUND(SUM(rmc.Netrate), 2), ROUND(SUM(cc.pc), 2) ,IFNULL (ROUND(SUM(Bc)),0)
FROM level1 L
LEFT JOIN (SELECT imcode,ItemName,ItemDescription,csid FROM Itemmaster)im
    ON (im.imcode=L.imcode)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Id,conditionofsupply FROM csmaster)cs
    ON (cs.id=im.csid)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT rmcode,rawmaterial FROM rawmaterialmaster)rm
    ON (rm.rmcode=L.rmcode)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Netrate,ScrapWeight*ScrapRate,GrossRate,CostingId,EnquiryId FROM rawmaterialcosting)rmc
    ON (L.EnquiryId=rmc.EnquiryId)  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Mutlipleunit*Rate AS pc,CostingId,EnquiryId FROM Conversioncosting)cc
    ON (L.EnquiryId=cc.EnquiryId)  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Numbers*Rate AS Bc,CostingId,EnquiryId FROM Boughtoutcosting)bc
    ON (L.EnquiryId=bc.EnquiryId)  
WHERE L.EnquiryId=5
GROUP BY rmc.CostingId,cc.CostingId,bc.CostingId
ORDER BY L.ID ASC
```

what is wrong in this, please help.

Comment: this  https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ also look like to be a problem.

Comment: Do the summing in the subquery

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that all the non-aggregated fields in the select clause are included in the group by clause. So try this:

```
SELECT rmc.CostingId,cc.CostingId,bc.CostingId, ROUND(SUM(rmc.Netrate), 2), ROUND(SUM(cc.pc), 2) ,IFNULL (ROUND(SUM(Bc)),0)
FROM level1 L
LEFT JOIN (SELECT imcode,ItemName,ItemDescription,csid FROM Itemmaster) im
    ON (im.imcode=L.imcode)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Id,conditionofsupply FROM csmaster) cs
    ON (cs.id=im.csid)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT rmcode,rawmaterial FROM rawmaterialmaster) rm
    ON (rm.rmcode=L.rmcode)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Netrate,ScrapWeight*ScrapRate,GrossRate,CostingId,EnquiryId FROM rawmaterialcosting) rmc
    ON (L.EnquiryId=rmc.EnquiryId)  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Mutlipleunit*Rate AS pc,CostingId,EnquiryId FROM Conversioncosting) cc
    ON (L.EnquiryId=cc.EnquiryId)  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Numbers*Rate AS Bc,CostingId,EnquiryId FROM Boughtoutcosting) bc
    ON (L.EnquiryId=bc.EnquiryId)  
WHERE L.EnquiryId=5
GROUP BY rmc.CostingId,cc.CostingId,bc.CostingId
ORDER BY L.ID ASC
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, am getting same 336.83 @cdaiga

Comment: Try again! There was not space between the aliases of the subqueries and the closing bracketes.

Comment: No am not getting desired value

Comment: I already explained the issue with your code. If you want to group by `rmc.CostingId,cc.CostingId,bc.CostingId` then they should be the only non aggregated fields in the select. Try again.